# I want to replace all <h1> tag with <h2> tag from my html page but keep first <h1> tag

Tags: jquery

I want to replace all `<h1>` tags with `<h2>` but keep first one.

here are example of tags that I have:

```html
<h1 class="section-title"></h1>

<h1 class="section-title"></h1>

<h1 class="section-title"></h1>

<h1 class="section-title"></h1>

<h1 class="section-title"></h1>
```

Here I to want keep first `<h1>` tag same but replace all other `<h1>` tag with `<h2>` tag.

This is what I have tried:

```js
       $(document).ready(function () {
         $('.section-title h1').each(function (i, el) {
           var c = $(el).attr("class");
           $(el).replaceWith('<h2 class="'+ c +'">' + $(el).html() +'</h2>')
         });
       });
```

But I want to keep the first tag as it is and replacing all of them.

Answer (score 1):

You can skip first occurrence of element using below syntax.

```
var all_h1_except_first = $('h1.section-title:not(:first)');
```

OR

```
var all_h1_except_first = $('h1.section-title:gt(0)');
```

Now You have H1 tags except first. You can do any operation with all other H1 tags which are stored in `all_h1_except_first` variable.

Comment: Note: https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/#eq1 :eq is deprecated